# xcode 12.5.1 crashes before archiving process complete

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store-connect, archive, macos-big-sur

I am using Macbook Pro 2020 M1 chip model with Mac OS 11.4, Xcode 12.5.1.

The app runs in the simulator, build succeeds fine. But when selected archive, when it's complete almost to 100%, Xcode crashes. And this occurs repeatedly every single time. When I opened it again and I went into the archives, there is none.

Please help me resolve this as now distribution is not possible. A Sample from the Xcode crash report is below,

Process: Xcode [31453] Path: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/MacOS/Xcode Identifier: com.apple.dt.Xcode Version: 12.5.1 (18212) Build Info: IDEFrameworks-18212000000000000~4 (12E507) App Item ID: 497799835 App External ID: 842555601 Code Type: ARM-64 (Native) Parent Process: ??? [1] Responsible: Xcode [31453] User ID: 501

Date/Time: 2021-07-04 13:23:53.754 +0530 OS Version: macOS 11.4 (20F71) Report Version: 12 Anonymous UUID: 9489B1DD-F35A-A215-90AF-7C1941B5D7BA

Sleep/Wake UUID: 3BC9647F-BA34-4DEB-AED5-2EAC16766C46

Time Awake Since Boot: 22000 seconds Time Since Wake: 4600 seconds

System Integrity Protection: enabled

Crashed Thread: 22 Dispatch queue: -[DVTSourceControlWorkspace init] (QOS: UNSPECIFIED)

Exception Type: EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT) Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000 Exception Note: EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY

Application Specific Information: ProductBuildVersion: 12E507 UNCAUGHT EXCEPTION (NSInvalidArgumentException): *** -[NSURL URLByAppendingPathComponent:]: component, components, or pathExtension cannot be nil. UserInfo: (null) Open FDs: 54/7168 Hints:

Backtrace: 0 __exceptionPreprocess (in CoreFoundation) 1 DVTFailureHintExceptionPreprocessor (in DVTFoundation) 2 objc_exception_throw (in libobjc.A.dylib) 3 -[NSURL(NSURLPathUtilities) URLByAppendingPathComponent:isDirectory:] (in Foundation) 4 -[DVTSourceControlWorkspaceBlueprint saveBlueprintInFolder:options:] (in DVTSourceControl) 5 __96+[IDEArchive _copySCMBlueprintFromWorkspace:toArchiveWithPath:usingFileManager:completionBlock:]_block_invoke (in IDEFoundation) 6 __107-[DVTSourceControlWorkspace blueprintWithRemoteRepositories:includingManagedWorkingCopies:completionBlock:]_block_invoke (in DVTSourceControl) 7 NSBLOCKOPERATION_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_BLOCK (in Foundation) 8 -[NSBlockOperation main] (in Foundation) 9 NSOPERATION_IS_INVOKING_MAIN (in Foundation) 10 -[NSOperation start] (in Foundation) 11 NSOPERATIONQUEUE_IS_STARTING_AN_OPERATION (in Foundation) 12 __NSOQSchedule_f (in Foundation) 13 _dispatch_block_async_invoke2 (in libdispatch.dylib) 14 _dispatch_client_callout (in libdispatch.dylib) 15 _dispatch_continuation_pop (in libdispatch.dylib) 16 _dispatch_async_redirect_invoke (in libdispatch.dylib) 17 _dispatch_root_queue_drain (in libdispatch.dylib) 18 _dispatch_worker_thread2 (in libdispatch.dylib) 19 _pthread_wqthread (in libsystem_pthread.dylib) 20 start_wqthread (in libsystem_pthread.dylib)

abort() called

Application Specific Signatures: NSInvalidArgumentException

Application Specific Backtrace 1: 0 CoreFoundation 0x000000019e228c78 __exceptionPreprocess + 240 1 DVTFoundation 0x00000001005acfc8 DVTFailureHintExceptionPreprocessor + 424 2 libobjc.A.dylib 0x000000019df510a8 objc_exception_throw + 60 3 Foundation 0x000000019ef23640 -[NSURL(NSURLPathUtilities) URLByAppendingPathComponent:isDirectory:] + 0 4 DVTSourceControl 0x000000010c64e354 -[DVTSourceControlWorkspaceBlueprint saveBlueprintInFolder:options:] + 124 5 IDEFoundation 0x000000010133bfcc __96+[IDEArchive _copySCMBlueprintFromWorkspace:toArchiveWithPath:usingFileManager:completionBlock:]_block_invoke + 128 6 DVTSourceControl 0x000000010c63e3f4 __107-[DVTSourceControlWorkspace blueprintWithRemoteRepositories:includingManagedWorkingCopies:completionBlock:]_block_invoke + 4096 7 Foundation 0x000000019ef31f50 NSBLOCKOPERATION_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_BLOCK + 24 8 Foundation 0x000000019ef31df8 -[NSBlockOperation main] + 104 9 Foundation 0x000000019ef31d88 NSOPERATION_IS_INVOKING_MAIN + 24 10 Foundation 0x000000019ef30fc8 -[NSOperation start] + 808 11 Foundation 0x000000019ef30c98 NSOPERATIONQUEUE_IS_STARTING_AN_OPERATION + 24 12 Foundation 0x000000019ef30b4c __NSOQSchedule_f + 184 13 libdispatch.dylib 0x000000019df0ab28 _dispatch_block_async_invoke2 + 148 14 libdispatch.dylib 0x000000019defbec0 _dispatch_client_callout + 20 15 libdispatch.dylib 0x000000019deff398 _dispatch_continuation_pop + 448 16 libdispatch.dylib 0x000000019defea28 _dispatch_async_redirect_invoke + 592 17 libdispatch.dylib 0x000000019df0d684 _dispatch_root_queue_drain + 388 18 libdispatch.dylib 0x000000019df0de90 _dispatch_worker_thread2 + 112 19 libsystem_pthread.dylib 0x000000019e0a7860 _pthread_wqthread + 216 20 libsystem_pthread.dylib 0x000000019e0a65d4 start_wqthread + 8

Comment: I would suggest trying the operation with a previous version of Xcode.